# Vue code overwriting nested property in Vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have setup a Vuex store in order to share the state across different components. One co-worker accidentally set a new property on the Vuex store without dispatching an action or committing a mutation, but nothing crashed and the application kept running. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

This is the structure of the store (simplified):

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    options: {},
  },
  actions: {
    setAttributes (context, payload) {
        context.commit('setAttributes', payload);
    },
    setPrice (context, payload) {
        context.commit('setPrice', payload);
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setAttributes (state, payload) {
      state.options.width = payload.width;
      state.options.height = payload.height;
    },
    setPrice (state, payload) {
        state.options.price = payload.price;
      },
  },
  getters: {
    options: state => {
      return state.options
    }
  }
});
```

And this is the structure of the Vue instance:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import { store } from './store/store';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            'options',
        ])
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$store.dispatch('setAttributes', {
            width: 100,
            height: 80,
        });
    } 
  });
```

In order to change the price I would have done something like:

```js
this.$store.dispatch('setPrice', {
    price: 800,
});
```

But we have found out that this is possible too:

```js
this.options.price = 800;
```

Is there a way to prevent it or should we avoid using nested objects in the shared state?

Comment: Enable `strict` mode in your store ~ https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: It is something I hadn’t investigated. I’d prefer an approach that could also run in production, but it’s a good starting point. Yes it does answer my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the answer was given by [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) in the comments, I'll quote it here and accept the answer:

> Enable strict mode in your store ~ vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html